# Reverse string without reversing custom characters swift

Tags: swift, string

Need to reverse strings without affecting characters which user can add by themself. Can somebody rewrite my code and suggest the solution?

```
func reverseWithoutFilter(FullText:String, TextToIgnore:String) -> String {
    let fullTextArray = FullText.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let textToIgnoreArray = TextToIgnore.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let result = fullTextArray.map{!textToIgnoreArray.contains($0) ? String($0.reversed()) : $0}
    return result.joined(separator: " ")
}
 
var result = reverseWithoutFilter(FullText: "FOX is good", TextToIgnore: "FOX")

// result will be "FOX si doog"

var result1 = reverseWithoutFilter(FullText: "Fox is good", TextToIgnore: "Fx")

// result will be "xoF si doog " characters "F" and "x" are not ignored
```

Comment: Can you tell what result you expect in each case ? I get the ones you show… except I get FOX si doog and not Fox si doog

Comment: @claude31
For example input: "Alloha 123" i want to reverse all characters except "h"and "3" so output will be: "aollhA 213"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson
Yes

Comment: That's not clear. What do you mean by ignoring some text ? Each character to be kept in position ?

Comment: @claude31
by ignoring some text i mean the characters which will stay in old position and do not swap in string.

Comment: it's unclear what 'text to to ignore' means. Should "Fx" just match "Fox" to give "xoF" or should it also match the first and last characters of "For once upon a time there lived a badger called Nix".  And what about "For once upon a time Far away from the lynx there lived a Fox called Foxie".  Using regex would make the intention far clearer.

Comment: @flanker I believe each word should be treated separately so the reversal logic is applied once per word. So Fox, For, Far will be changed to Fox, Fro and Fro no matter where in the sentence they are or how many times they occur.

Comment: That was my best guess too, but the Q could have been clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should

- extract components in fullText, as you did
- in each, get the the positions of each char in textToIgnore
- remove those chars in each component
- reverse each component
- insert back the removed chars in the reverted components

Here is a code for this. Can be optimized for sure, but it works.

```
extension StringProtocol {
    subscript(offset: Int) -> Character {
        self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)]
    }
}

func reverseWithoutFilter2(fullText: String, textToIgnore: String) -> String {
    
    // For example: "Alloha 123", excluding "h3"
    let fullTextArray = fullText.components(separatedBy: " ")
    // fullTextArray = ["Alloha", "123"]
    var posOfChars : [[String:[Int]]] = [] // posOfChars[i] is a dict [String:[Int]], giving the positions of each excluded chars in component i
    // keep positions of excluded chars
    for (i, comp) in fullTextArray.enumerated() {
        posOfChars.append( [:] )
        for c in textToIgnore {
            for (pos, charInComp) in comp.enumerated() {
                if charInComp == c {
                    if posOfChars[i][String(c)] == nil {
                        posOfChars[i][String(c)] = [pos]
                    } else {
                        posOfChars[i][String(c)]!.append(pos)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // posOfChars[0]["h"] = [4]
    // posOfChars[1]["3"] = [2]

    var newTextArray = fullTextArray
    // Remove excluded chars in each comp
    for (i, comp) in fullTextArray.enumerated() {
        for c in textToIgnore {
            newTextArray[i] = newTextArray[i].replacingOccurrences(of: String(c), with: "")
        }
    }
    // newTextArray = ["Alloa", "12"]
    
    // Now we reverse each component
    newTextArray = newTextArray.map() { String($0.reversed()) }
    // newTextArray = ["aollA", "21"]
    
    // Put back the excluded chars
    for i in 0..<newTextArray.count {
        for toRestore in posOfChars[i] { // ["h": [4] ]
            let str = toRestore.key // "h" but need to get a char
            let firstChar = str[0] 
            for pos in toRestore.value {
                let posIndex = newTextArray[i].index(newTextArray[i].startIndex, offsetBy: pos)
                newTextArray[i].insert(firstChar, at: posIndex)
            }
        }
    }

    return newTextArray.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

You may have noticed it doesn't work for
let result = reverseWithoutFilter2(fullText: "B3lloha 123", textToIgnore: "h3")

Need to change logic a little:

```
func reverseWithoutFilter2(fullText: String, textToIgnore: String) -> String {
    
    // For example: "B3lloha 123", excluding "h3"
    let fullTextArray = fullText.components(separatedBy: " ")
    // fullTextArray = ["B3lloha", "123"]
    var posOfChars : [[String:[Int]]] = [] // posOfChars[i] is a dict [String:[Int]], giving the positions of each excluded chars in component i
    // keep positions of excluded chars
    for (i, comp) in fullTextArray.enumerated() {
        posOfChars.append( [:] )
        for c in textToIgnore {
            for (pos, charInComp) in comp.enumerated() {
                if charInComp == c {
                    if posOfChars[i][String(c)] == nil {
                        posOfChars[i][String(c)] = [pos]
                    } else {
                        posOfChars[i][String(c)]!.append(pos)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // posOfChars[0]["h"] = [5]
    // posOfChars[0]["3"] = [1]
    // posOfChars[1]["3"] = [2]

    var newTextArray = fullTextArray
    // Remove excluded chars in each comp
    for (i, comp) in fullTextArray.enumerated() {
        for c in textToIgnore {
            newTextArray[i] = newTextArray[i].replacingOccurrences(of: String(c), with: "")
        }
    }
    // newTextArray = ["Blloa", "12"]
    
    // Now we reverse each component
    newTextArray = newTextArray.map() { String($0.reversed()) }
    // newTextArray = ["aollB", "21"]
    
    // Put back the excluded chars

    for i in 0..<fullTextArray.count { // Get each component
        // let us build the array of keys, in correct order (1, "3"), (5, "h")
        var orderedArray = [(Int, String)] ()
        let maxIndex = newTextArray[i].count // 7 for B3lloha
        for toRestore in posOfChars[i] { // ["h": [5], "3": [1] ]
            for item in toRestore.value {
                orderedArray.append((item, toRestore.key))
            }
            orderedArray = orderedArray.sorted() { $0.0 < $1.0 } // orderedArray [(1, "3"), (5, "h")]
            
        }
        for (index, str) in orderedArray {
            let posIndex = newTextArray[i].index(newTextArray[i].startIndex, offsetBy: index)
            let char = str[0]
            newTextArray[i].insert(char, at: posIndex)
        }
    }

    return newTextArray.joined(separator: " ")
}
```